# How to stop an AsyncTask while DriverManager.getConnection in running?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I would like to explain the situation to introduce you into my problem. I have an `AsyncTask` on Android which tries to connect to a database through **jdbc** driver. On my `doInBackground`, I have the following instruction:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, connInfo.getUserName(), connInfo.getPassword());
```

The problem comes when I try to cancel the `AsyncTask` and that the task is trying to execute the previous instruction.

I want the user to have the option of cancelling the `AsyncTask` and immediately execute it again to connect to another database. When I cancel the first `AsyncTask` and I start another one, until the first task achieves to get the connection and finish his `doInBackground` method, the second task can't get its own connection.

After this complicated explanation, I think that it is not possible for the `DriverManager` to execute `getConnection` while another instance is executing the same method.

What I want to achieve is: once the user cancels the first `AsyncTask`, abort the execution of `DriverManager.getConnection()`, in order to allow a second task to execute this instruction as soon as possible, without making the user to wait until `doInBackground` finishes on first task.

I copy part of my code:

```
class DBConnectionTask extends AsyncTask <ConnectionInfo,Void,Void>{//connection using JDBC driver

    private ConnectionInfo connInfo;
    private Connection conn;
    private Statement st;
    private Activity activity;
    GlobalData g;
    String url;


    ProgressDialog loadingCircle;


    public DBConnectionTask(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        loadingCircle=ProgressDialog.show(activity,"","Trying to connect, please wait...",false);
        loadingCircle.setCancelable(true);
        loadingCircle.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // actually could set running = false; right here, but I'll
                // stick to contract.
                cancel(true); //cancela asynctask y no hace el onPostExecute

            }
        });
    }


    protected Void doInBackground(ConnectionInfo... params) {

        connInfo = params[0];

        connect();

        return null;
    }
```

And the `connect()` method

```
    protected void connect(){

        try
        {
            //part of the code here is ommited

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, connInfo.getUserName(), connInfo.getPassword());
            System.out.println("Acaba doInBackGround " + connInfo.getAlias());
            //st = conn.createStatement();
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SqlMenu.class);
            activity.startActivity(intent);

        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
            cancel(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
            cancel(true);
        }
        finally {
            loadingCircle.dismiss();//loadingCircle.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

I want to make the task cancelled interrupt its attempt to connect to database just at the moment the user cancels the task.

Comment: I deleted the answer since it didn't work for you.  For this to work, somehow you need to force an exception to be thrown in your `connect()` method.  Not sure if it's possible here though.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. If I get the solution, I will post it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can not interrupt this `DriverManager.getConnection(url, connInfo.getUserName(), connInfo.getPassword());` statement as it is predefined method and you don't have any control over it. But you can do interrupt at some points where predefined methods are getting finished.

See comments following in your edited code:

```
protected void connect(){

        try
        {
            //part of the code here is ommited
            if(isCancelled())
            {
                return; // return control if ayncTask is cancelled.
            }
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, connInfo.getUserName(), connInfo.getPassword());
            System.out.println("Acaba doInBackGround " + connInfo.getAlias());
            if(isCancelled())
            {
                return; // return control if ayncTask is cancelled.
            }

            // query data from database .
            // if you are going to use a loop to extract data form cursor, same condition can be used in that loop also.
            // so whenever ayncTask is cancelled it can be interrupted.

            if(isCancelled())
            {
                return; // return control if ayncTask is cancelled.
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SqlMenu.class);
            activity.startActivity(intent);

        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
            cancel(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
            cancel(true);
        }
        finally {
            loadingCircle.dismiss();//loadingCircle.dismiss();
        }
    }
```